# Extracting part of a string

Tags: python

So if I have a string
`randomwordabcrandomwordsxyzrandomwords` and want to extract `abcrandomwordsxyz` how would this be achieved, with abc and xyz being constant. I'm very new to python, so anything simple would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using regex:

one way:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'randomwordabcrandomwordsxyzrandomwords'
>>> m = re.search('(abc.*?xyz)', s)
>>> m.group()
'abcrandomwordsxyz'
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> re.findall('abc.*?xyz', s)
['abcrandomwordsxyz']
>>>
```

If you ve multiple 'xyz', then it will match up to the first one. (non greedy match)

Last one is not a good way but just an option :

```
>>> s[s.rfind('abc'):s.rfind('xyz')+3]
'abcrandomwordsxyz'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer :

```
import re

mystring = 'randomwordabcrandomwordsxyzrandomwords'
result   = ""

regex = re.match(r'.*?(abc.*?xyz).*?$',mystring)

if regex:
    result = regex.group(1)

print result
```